# How do I update user access token with post request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-authentication

I load application once, receive signed_request and retrieve user token from it, then all transitions in the iframe are done using internal links (no signed request).

I have several use cases I need to deal with. User access token expired just before:

1. User clicked on the next link (not ajax) and sent get request
2. User filled the form and sent post request
3. User sent ajax request to the server that needs to access facebook

Nr 1 is the most obvious case, I can simply redirect user to /authorize as there is no transaction. Nr3 can be solved in the same way parsing the special error from the server and redirecting to /authorize.

Nr2, is the most unpleasant case as I am using non-transactional mongodb. So the only solution I see is - before doing anything, I need to check the access token against /me?, if it's invalid, save the whole request body in the session, redirect to /authorize and then deal with request once again. However, if it's valid there is no guarantee that my transaction is successful but I am fine with this.

So I think the real question is.. how do you deal with these situations? How do you refresh token? How do you handle them? Maybe I am missing something obvious?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP sdk you can call:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

In javascript sdk you can use:

```
FB.getLoginStatus
```

to get a fresh access token any time you need. Use [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1251291415) to check tokens. Mind the permissions to get token as well.